# C# object sender - getting the Method from which it was called

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got these Methods:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          //Changes the Text in the RichBox, EXAMPLE:
          richtTextBox.Text = "Now Changed and calling Method richTextBox_TextChanged";
    }
```

And,

```
 private void richTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
         //Wants something like that
         if(called from button_click)
         {
           //DO SOMETHING
         }
         else
         {
           //DO SOMETHING
         }
 }
```

How can I handle this, to know if it was called from the Button_click?
Do I have to use the object sender to get informations? But how?

Hope u guys can help me

Comment: The first thing comes into mind is that you can have some kind of indicator or flag which will be set once button_Click is called and you can check that flag in richTextBox_TextChanged and reset. But I believe this is the straight forward solution and there must be much better solutions for such cases which will be known by desktop application developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a flag:

```
private bool _isInButtonClick;

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      try
      {
          _isInButtonClick = true;
          //Changes the Text in the RichBox, EXAMPLE:
          richtTextBox.Text = "Now Changed and calling Method richTextBox_TextChanged";
      }
      finally
      {
          _isInButtonClick = false;
      }
}


 private void richTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
         if(_isInButtonClick)
         {
           //DO SOMETHING
         }
         else
         {
           //DO SOMETHING
         }
 }
```

Comment: resetting '_isInButtonClick' in finally block seems can make problems, as it can be executed before 'if' block in 'richTextBox_TextChanged', so I think would be better to reset the value in 'richTextBox_TextChanged'.

Comment: So this isnt working, he never walks into:          if(_isInButtonClick)
         {
           //DO SOMETHING
         }

Comment: @eMi yes... better to reset that flag in richTextBox_TextChanged and you will have the result you want.

Comment: so u mean, I should do: _isInButtonClick = false; in the richTextBox_TextChanged? before the 'if' Block?

Answer (score 2):

```
private void richTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Here `sender` is the richTextBox, not the button that changed the text.

You could go into the stack trace to discover if the button click is on the call stack, but that's overkill (like using a nuke to crack a walnut).

Add a flag (bool) to your form, set it to true in the button click, and check it in the TextChanged event, then at the end of the button click, set it to false again.

If you do this I would advise wrapping this `signal` logic in a class that implements IDispose and use it in `using` statements.

That said, are you sure you need this functionality?

Comment: sounds complicated^^ I thought it would be possible to do something with the sender..